# error between FosRestBundle and SensioFramewordBundle

Tags: php, symfony4, fosrestbundle

I installed the two libraries FOSRest and Sensio but I have the following error:

```
You must enable the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle view annotations to use the ViewResponseListener. Did you forget to install and enable the TwigBundle?
```

While I do not need Twig since my API will send everything back to json.

I still try to install it but I still have problems.

Here is the configuration for Sensio:

```
sensio_framework_extra:
router:
    annotations: false
view:
    annotations: true
request:
    converters: true
```

And for FOSREST:

```
fos_rest:
body_converter:
    enabled: true
serializer:
    serialize_null: true
view:
    formats: { json: true, xml: false, rss: false }
    view_response_listener: true
format_listener:
    rules:
        - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 'json' }
```

Nothing very important.

I hope you can help me.

Thanking you

Answer (score 1):

While this is not the most satisfying solution, I ended up installing TwigBundle after a very frustrating hour, just as suggested by the message.

```
composer require symfony/twig-bundle
```

This should solve your error.

---

I say this is not the most satisfying solution because just like you I did not need Twig templating at all so it didn't feel natural to install it. I couldn't take much time to figure out why FOSRest would need this. Does it rely on some Twig code bricks to run? I don't know, this is just the best and quicker workaround I found.